# Is there an index that quantifies the degree of independence of dependent random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Is there an index that quantifies the degree of independence of dependent random variables? Suppose there are n dependent and identically distributed variables, I was thinking of the ratio covariance/variance. The lower this quantity, the higher the "degree of independence" of these dependent variables. Is there such an index? or what is Covariance/Variance called?

Comment: Well done on coming up with the regression coefficient estimator without knowing about it, or regression for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the linear regression coefficient in the simple linear model. If $$y_i=a+bx_i$$ with $i=1,...,n$, then $$b=cov(Y,X)/var(X).$$ Similarly, the Pearson correlation is defined as $$cov(Y,X)/(var(X)var(Y))^{1/2}.$$ In general there is no measure of independence but only a measure of dependence, that is the correlation, or regression coefficients in a statistical model. of $Y$ given $X$.